# Why do I have to stage a file in order to make git realise that a conflict has been resolved?

Tags: git

Problem: I change multiple lines, and stage + commit all but one of them, then I want to push the commit. However, before I push them I want to merge from another branch to see if there's a conflict to be resolved as well.

Uh-oh, a conflict! I fix it, but in order to make git agree that it's fixed, I *have* to stage the entire file. Noooo, I want to keep that single line unstaged. Staging the entire file will bury that line among 1000 lines of conflict-resolved changes (so finding it and unstaging it will take days ;-).

Why can't I just tell git "listen, relax, forget it, it's not a problem anymore, I want to just leave things as they are now - when I'm done with the final fix to that single line I *promise* I'll stage everything (eventually;-) and commit it".

Am I missing something? Is there a simple workflow that'll get around this issue?

Cheers,
Stein

Comment: If the merge brought the single file not staged into conflict, then you must resolve the conflicts, there is no way around this.  You could just do the merge after pushing.

Comment: You could use `git add -p` to stage some of the changed lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Staging can be done patch by patch rather than by whole files. Use a git client or git add -p and stage only the parts you want to be part of this commit (probably the parts around the merged areas).

Comment: Thanks. I'm marking it as solved, as it resolves my (original) gripe about having to stage the entire file. Just realised, though, that the issue of "finding that single line among 1000 others", isn't really solved, it's just that I'll have to find it and not stage it rather than staging it all, then finding it and unstaging it. Or... couldn't I stash that line change, merge, stage, commit, then pop? I'll try it.

Comment: Oh, and I really would like to mark @torek's answer as a solution as well, as he does give the same info, just a lot of background stuff as well. But that doesn't seem to be possible.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you have to `git add` to resolve the conflict is that the conflict is actually stored *in the index*, which is the same place that `git add` updates.  And, unfortunately, this storage disrupts the carefully tweaked version you stored earlier.

#### Description

Fundamentally, Git stores every file having to do with the current-and-next commits in *three* places, not just two.

- There is a copy of every file, stored in Git's special Gitty format (compressed etc), permanently and read-only, as part of the HEAD commit.  That is, if `.git/HEAD` contains `ref: refs/heads/branchX` so that you are on branch `branchX`, and `branchX` means "commit `1234567...`", then the commit whose hash ID is `1234567...` contains a complete snapshot of your source tree.  (No big deal so far, nothing surprising here.)
- There's also a copy of every file, stored in plain format—not some special Gitty variety—so that you can edit and compile and run programs and so on, in your *work-tree*.  (Nothing surprising here either.)
- But in between, there is a *third* copy of every file.  That third copy is normally, and initially, the same as the `HEAD` commit copy.  (In fact, it's in the special Gitty format, which replaces the actual files with a hash ID.  Plus, that hash ID is kept in an ordinary data file, `.git/index`, along with some cache information, so it hardly takes any extra space at all:

  ```
  $ ls -l .git/index
  ...  300971 Dec  6 20:23 .git/index
  ```

  for an index of the Git tree for Git, for instance.)

When you run `git add` on a file, what you're really doing is copying it back into the index.  When you run `git add <file>`, Git turns `<file>` into the special Gitty format—this is when it actually goes into the repository!—and shoves the resulting hash into the index.  If you `git add -p <file>` and stage most but not all of it, the most-but-not-all version is what's now stored in the index.

Whatever is in the index, is what Git will snapshot into the *next* commit.  The new commit will then take over as "the current commit", so that HEAD—i.e., `branchX`—will now mean, say, "commit `fedcba9...`", which will be permanent and read-only and contain the final snapshot of your file.  (Meanwhile the hash `1234567...` is now remembered via the fact that it's the *parent* hash stored in `fedcba9...`.)

In other words, after committing, the index matches the HEAD commit again, because the HEAD commit was *made from* the index.  Everything is still there in slot zero, undisturbed.

#### How `git merge` wrecks this

Each of these index entries is a *stage zero* entry.  Stage zero is the normal stage, for a unconflicted entry.  But each index entry actually has up to *four* slots.  You can either have something in stage 0, or—by removing the stage zero entry—you can have something in slots 1, 2, and/or 3.  When `git merge` discovers that it has to merge a file, it does just that: it wipes out the stage zero entry, copies the *merge base* version to stage#1, copies the HEAD or `--ours` version to stage#2, and copies the remaining `--theirs` version to stage#3.

Git leaves it up to the low level file merge handler to resolve the conflicts, if it can (and if you use `-X ours` or `-X theirs`, it always can).  If the low level driver does resolve the conflicts, that driver will `git add` the work-tree copy for you.  If not, it leaves the conflicts *in* the work-tree file, and leaves the three nonzero-stage entries in place.

When you `git add` the final version, you tell Git: *Remove stages 1 through 3, and put whatever's in the work-tree in as stage 0.*  (This remains true even with `git add -p`.)

Until you do this, `git commit` cannot commit, because it can only commit entries that are stored in the stage-zero slot.